# Persistent errors with pgfplots bar graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code, I'm trying to make a bar chart with the data below (+ code). Some of the outputs include:

- Overfull \vbox (10.22557pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
- Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `OTPr' has not been defin
  ed with 'symbolic x coords={11-331p, 11-332p, 11-333p, 11-334p, 11-335p, 11-336
  p, 11-337p, 11-338p, 11-339p, 11-340p, 11-341p, 11-342p, 11-343p, 11-344p, 11-3
  45p, 11-346p, 11-347p, 11-348p, 11-48p, 11-49p, 11-50p, 11-51p}... Maybe it has
  been misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]OTPr?.

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
      Endorsements & Zero & One \\
      OTPr & 1.29 & 4.20 \\ 
      OTPa & 2.80 & 3.16 \\ 
      ASTPr & 3.24 & 2.37 \\ 
      ASTPa & 4.35 & 1.18 \\ 
      OTCPr & 5.79 & 0.14 \\ 
      OTCPa & 6.00 & 1.18 \\ 
      IFOPr & 7.21 & 2.45 \\ 
      IFOPa & 8.38 & 3.28 \\ 
      CSOPr & 9.06 & 4.66 \\ 
      CSOPa & 8.58 & 5.35 \\ 
      CTPr & 7.99 & 6.24 \\ 
      CTPa & 6.97 & 7.24 \\ 
      CADEPr & 5.38 & 8.49 \\
      CADEPa & 4.40 & 9.64 \\ 
      IFCPr & 3.92 & 8.40  \\ 
      IFCPa & 2.26 & 7.26 \\ 
      CSCPr & 1.18 & 6.55 \\ 
      CSCPa & 2.67 & 5.30 \\ 
      OPr & 3.82 & 4.12 \\ 
      OPa & 4.53 & 3.88 \\ 
      CPr & 5.38 & 2.49 \\ 
      CPa & 6.45 & 1.64 \\
    }\mydataC
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      enlarge x limits={rel=0.5},
      ybar = 3,
      bar width=0.75cm,
      width=\textwidth,
      height=.4\textwidth,
      legend style={at={(0.5,1)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      symbolic x coords={11-331p, 11-332p, 11-333p, 11-334p, 11-335p, 11-336p, 11-337p, 11-338p, 11-339p, 11-340p, 11-341p, 11-342p, 11-343p, 11-344p, 11-345p, 11-346p, 11-347p, 11-348p, 11-48p, 11-49p, 11-50p, 11-51p},
      xtick=data,
      nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplotspointmeta} 
        \num[
          round-mode = places,
          round-precision = 2,
        ]{\pgfmathresult}},
      nodes near coords align={vertical},
      ymin=0,ymax=10,
      ylabel={Rates (\%)},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=Endorsements,y=Zero]{\mydataC};
    \addplot table[x=Endorsements,y=One]{\mydataC};
    \legend{$Zero$, $One$},
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Bar chart.}
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your `symbolic x coords` are not defined in `\mydataC` table (as notified you error's message) . So,  it is not clear, what you like to achieve by defining your `symbolic x coords`. X-coordinates labels? If so, this is wrong approach.

To me is somehow logical, that you after the following:

[image: example 1]

which is produced by:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
     Endorsements & Zero & One \\
      OTPr      & 1.29 & 4.20 \\
      OTPa      & 2.80 & 3.16 \\
      ASTPr     & 3.24 & 2.37 \\
      ASTPa     & 4.35 & 1.18 \\
      OTCPr     & 5.79 & 0.14 \\
      OTCPa     & 6.00 & 1.18 \\
      IFOPr     & 7.21 & 2.45 \\
      IFOPa     & 8.38 & 3.28 \\
      CSOPr     & 9.06 & 4.66 \\
      CSOPa     & 8.58 & 5.35 \\
      CTPr      & 7.99 & 6.24 \\
      CTPa      & 6.97 & 7.24 \\
      CADEPr    & 5.38 & 8.49 \\
      CADEPa    & 4.40 & 9.64 \\
      IFCPr     & 3.92 & 8.40 \\
      IFCPa     & 2.26 & 7.26 \\
      CSCPr     & 1.18 & 6.55 \\
      CSCPa     & 2.67 & 5.30 \\
      OPr       & 3.82 & 4.12 \\
      OPa       & 4.53 & 3.88 \\
      CPr       & 5.38 & 2.49 \\
      CPa       & 6.45 & 1.64 \\
    }\mydataC
    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=10mm,
    ybar=1mm,
    bar width=3.4mm,
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    enlarge y limits={.15, upper},
% y ticks style and label
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    ylabel={Rates (\si{\percent})},
%
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
% x axis ticks and style
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\mydataC}{Endorsements},    % <-------------------
    table/x expr = \coordindex,                         % <-------------------
    x tick label style = {rotate=45, anchor=east, inner sep=2pt},
% legend
    legend style = {legend pos=north east,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}
                    },
    ]
\addplot [fill=blue!80!black]
            table [y=Zero]  {\mydataC};
            \addlegendentry{Zero};
\addplot [fill=yellow!80!black]
            table [y=One]  {\mydataC};
            \addlegendentry{One};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

IN the case, that you like to change `xtick` labels, than you need to replace code line

```
xticklabels from table={\mydataC}{Endorsements},
```

with

```
    xticklabels={11-331p, 11-332p, 11-333p, 11-334p, 11-335p, 11-336p, 11-337p, 11-338p, 11-339p, 11-340p, 11-341p, 11-342p, 11-343p, 11-344p, 11-345p, 11-346p, 11-347p, 11-348p, 11-48p, 11-49p, 11-50p, 11-51p},
```

and you will get:

[image: example 2]

Comment: Thanks @Zarko! I have one more question. Is there a way I can rotate the entire graph by 90°? Essentially, showing it landscape? I would also like to hide top x-axis and right y-axis?

Comment: @FranjoIM, for have only x- and y-axis, you need to insert `axis lines=left,` after `begin{axis}`. About rotating image is not clear, what you like to achieve. Interchange `x-` and `y-`axis, or only rotate image as it is? Where should be caption of image etc. For all this  we (i) need more information about your document. The best way is to ask follow-up question (with link to this one) and explain what is the problem. It might be solution enclose image in `sideways` environment. To be more certain, more information is needed (as I already noted).

Comment: So I flipped x and y values, then I used  `xtick pos=upper, xticklabel pos=upper, ytick pos=left, yticklabel pos=left,` which seems to do the trick. However it might be better if I just rotated the entire thing instead. I tried `sidewaysfigure`, but that forces the entire figure at the end of the file. Is there any way to force `sidewaysfigure` to a specific page?

Comment: @FranjoIM, I cant say anything certain since i haven't any information about your document. `sidewaysfigure` has the same positioning options as standard `figure` float`. I suggest you (again) that ask new question as I suggest in my earlier comment is the best (actually the only one) way to get adequate help. For now I can only speak general as I already did in previous comment.